# Issue in accessing member details of groups in ADUser

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch details of the members of specific group in AD. 
Below is the cmdlet I am using

```
Get-ADGroupMember <GroupName> -Property members
```

It throws the below error:

> Get-ADGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Property'.

The cmdlet is working fine without the option "Property". Is there anything that I need to install to use this option. Currently I am working on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the raw `members` property, you should use `Get-ADGroup` instead of `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
Get-ADGroup groupname -Property members
```

or, if you want only the member values:

```
(Get-ADGroup groupname -Property members).members
```